# Цикл событий & массив объектов класса

Tags: c#

Каким образом мне надо сделать поле класса из массива, чтобы туда через textbox добавлялись имена(для их последующего использования в таблице, например)? Или массив объектов класса. На Windows Form

```
namespace л_б
{
    public class Box
    {
        private string[] name;
        private int width;
        private int length;
        private int weight;
        private int age;
        private int counter;

        public Box(string name) => Name = name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => name[counter];
            set
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value));
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Не может быть пустого значения!");
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace л_б
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Главная точка входа для приложения.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            Box[] NameBox = new Box[5];
        }
    }
}
namespace л_б
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Box[] NameBox = new Box[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Box.Name[i] = new Box(textBox1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я так понял, вы хотите вводить несколько имён. Для этого нужно использовать несколько текстбоксов. Или, лучше, компонент наподобие DataGridView. В крайнем случае, если используется один TextBox, то ввод нужно сделать по нажатию на кнопку: в событии Button_Click данные берутся из текстбокса и помещаются куда вам надо. Уберите ваши TextChanged. Это для начала.

Comment: Да, я не успел закончить, так как выходит ошибка: 
Ошибка CS1061 "Box[]" не содержит определения "name", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "name", принимающий тип "Box[]" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понял предназначение класса `Box`. Не понял почему внутри него массив и зачем вносить изменения после каждого изменения внутри `textbox`.

Сделал для Вас пример. На форме находится 3 элемента. `TextBox`, `ListBox` и `Button`. Так же у нас есть список из объектов `NameHolder`. Всякий раз когда пользователь нажимает на Button, мы создаем объект `NameHolder` и помещаем его в список. Так же мы обновляем `ListBox`, чтобы показать текущий список.

Листинг :

```
public class NameHolder
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public NameHolder(string name)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(name)} cannot be null or empty");
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly List<NameHolder> _nameHolders = new List<NameHolder>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = _nameHolders;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        _nameHolders.Add(new NameHolder(textBox1.Text)); 
        listBox1.DataSource = _nameHolders;
        listBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Пример работы программы :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. По поводу того что я там в событии кнопки манипулирую с `DataSource` - я это выяснил опытным путем. Так как `Refresh()` контрола ничего мне не дал. Поэтому я и подумал, что можно по идее просто сделать перепривязку. Я не знаю что будет если в листе будет находиться более 100 элементов, как это повлияет. Я не рекомендую использовать такую перепривязку. Я считаю что это плохая практика. В рамках обзорного решения примера, я ее оставлю.

**UPD** Если нужны массивы:

```
    private readonly NameHolder[] _nameHolders = new NameHolder[5];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.DataSource = _nameHolders;
        
        listBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        for (var index = 0; index < _nameHolders.Length; ++index)
        {
            if(_nameHolders[index] != null)
                continue;

            _nameHolders[index] = new NameHolder(textBox1.Text);
            break;
        }

        listBox1.DataSource = _nameHolders;
        listBox1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: мне нужно, с помощью конструкторов, свойств, массива объектов класса предложить ввести пользователю через форму поля заданного класса Box, для, например, 5 человек

Comment: @ЛевиЙоффер Добавил в ответ кусок кода, если нужны массивы. Вам не составит труда применить данный пример для Ваших целей.

Comment: `Refresh` в данном случае не нужен; его следует удалить. | Перепривязка данных сделана правильно: сперва присваиваем null, затем - новое значение.

Comment: Чтобы обойтись без перепривязки данных, следует использовать коллекцию, которая имеет специальные события изменения коллекции: BindingList, ObservableCollection.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov по поводу данных коллекций я вкурсе. но разве WinForms умеет с ними работать? пойду проверю. по поводу Refresh() учту. Спасибо!